# How to show an iplot without opening an additional window into r shiny

Tags: r, graph, shiny, interactive, iplots

I'm trying to build interactive graphs in my shiny app. The user should be able to click on bars and see where the cases are displayed in another graph for example like a scatterplot next to the barplot.

There are different r packages, that are doing a great job: iplot, rggobi, acinonyx. I also found qtlcharts, but it does not exactly what I wanted. The problem is, I can't figure out, how to integrate different iplots into my shiny app boxes. Is there any way preventing iplots from opening separate windows for the graphs?

In acinonyx you can say window=FALSE, which prevents opening the java window of the graph. But the graph isn't displayed in the box as well. You could add/move the iplot into icontainer, iVisual or iWindow, but none of them can be integrated into the shiny boxes in the ui without printing the error: unsupported data frame or doing nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question: building reactive ggplots in shiny and adding coloured layers to one plot if the other plot is clicked will do the job.